# Display two values in the dropdown jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am making a search feature using jQuery autocomplete where the data is coming from a json. 
The search is supposed to display the full name of a person, but since the first name and last name are in two different fields in the json, I am finding it hard to display both the first name and last name together in the autocomplete dropdown.

Is it somehow possible to concatenate the two values together when one searches for either and display the full name in the dropdown ?

Example of JSON:

```
{
    "GetContactsResult": [
    {
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Doe",
        "LocalNumber": "555000",
        "MobileNumber": "555000"
            },
            {
                "FirstName": "Jane",
                "LastName": "Doe",
                "LocalNumber": "555000",
                "MobileNumber": "555000"

                    }]}
```

Here is my code/html:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">



        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#typedText").autocomplete({
                source: function ( request, response ) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "data.json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var sData = data.GetContactsResult.filter(function(v) { 
                                var re = new RegExp( request.term, "i" );
                                return re.test(v.FirstName);

                            });

                            response( $.map( sData, function ( item ) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.FirstName
                                };
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2,
            });
        });

        </script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>click function</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input  id="typedText">
        <input type="button" id="getValue" value="Type value">
    </body>
    </html>
```

So just to make it more clear, I am trying to get "John Doe" being displayed in the autocomplete and not just  "John".

Comment: Simply do `label: item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass the full item object to the response function.

So in your label object do this:

```
label: item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName;
```

Should return the full name.

Comment: Thanks !!! I was earlier trying to do this 

label: item.FirstName + " " + label: item.LastName;.

But do you know if it is possible to get the same result if I type the last name first ?

Comment: To the last, yes, but you need to include another condition into the filter function.

Comment: Please notice that search values with + | and so forth will fail in your regex test because they aren't escaped.

Comment: Ok i have been trying to add a condition to my filter function, but I must say I have no idea on where to place it. 
And regarding the regex not being escaped. Do i need to do that before the second condition will work ?

Comment: `return re.test(v.FirstName) || re.test(v.LastName);`